Is it possible to Highlight a JavaScript Script inside of a JSP file in Eclipse?
i work mostly with JS , JSP and JAVA files , I have tried several different solutions , but it does not seem to be possible to highlight whatever is inside of
<script type="text/javascript">...</script> as JavaScript in a way that it autocompletes and colors it as it does as in a native JS File
I tried Wild Web Dev , chaning Syntax Colors , and other stuff , is it simply impossible ?

Yes, as far as I know, not via Eclipse Wild Web Developer, but via WTP which is part of the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers. The TextMate Language Pack from TM4E seems also to provide syntax highlighting (but no support for the Java code as WTP does): https://stackoverflow.com/a/78537534/6505250

There is extremely limited support for it in the Web Tools Platform's JSP Editor. In older releases, APIs from the Java Development Tools (JDT) and JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT) allowed the JSP editor to support syntax coloring, content assist, and reformatting in keeping with the Java and JavaScript Editors' preferences, but after multiple parser migrations, the language support for JavaScript from JSDT itself stagnated. The focus for JavaScript support has since moved to Wild Web Developer, but it attempts to support all the web languages that aren't JSP while offering no APIs for reuse like JSDT once did (it is based on reusing what's available from language servers; I still find it to be ill-fitting for the Eclipse UI relative to other editors).

Okay i understand so there is no solution for my problem ?

The JSP Editor will highlight JavaScript, but not do much more for it, and definitely not as much as it used to do.

To make JavaScript higlight and autocompete in JSP files on Eclips try this:
Go Window > Preferences > JavaScript > Editor > Syntax Coloring. Tick "Enable".

Go Window > Preferences > JavaScript > Editor > Content Assist. Tick "Auto Activation". Set delay and triggers.

For JSP, right-click project, Configure > Convert to JavaScript Project.

Maybe use Aptana Studio for better support for Eclipse.
Good luck!
